# Error "InvalidOperationException: The required column 'Codigo' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation." but code still works

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

So basically, my asp.net Core application is a type of "shopping cart" that transfers things from one sql database table to another sql database table. The part that does this is basically my "Edit" function.

```
     public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(NewClass nc)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var num = HttpContext.Request.Form["txtFirst"].ToString();
            await _db.DataBaseData.FromSqlRaw("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Codigo FROM Carro.dbo.Carro WHERE CODIGO= {1}) BEGIN INSERT INTO Carro.dbo.Carro SELECT * ,{0} FROM Datos.dbo.DataBaseData WHERE CODIGO= {1} END", num, nc.Codigo).ToListAsync();
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        return View(nc);
    }
```

The problem is whenever I click the button that completes the function in my application, I get the following error page: [Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRyMt.png)

The thing is, my code does work and the item is added. The code DOES work.

What can I do to get rid of the error or the error page? I'm using NET.Core 6.0 btw

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and so I'm answering my question in case it helps anybody. After a lot of research, I found out that the function .FromSqlRaw is used for Select queries. I changed it to .ExecuteSqlRaw and it fixed the problem. My line before was

```
await _db.DataBaseData.FromSqlRaw("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Codigo FROM Carro.dbo.Carro WHERE CODIGO= {1}) BEGIN INSERT INTO Carro.dbo.Carro SELECT * ,{0} FROM Datos.dbo.DataBaseData WHERE CODIGO= {1} END", num, nc.Codigo).ToListAsync();
```

That was giving me the error. The changed line that worked was:

```
 _db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT CODIGO FROM Carro.dbo.Carro WHERE CODIGO = {0}) BEGIN INSERT INTO Carro.dbo.Carro SELECT *, {1} FROM Datos.dbo.DataBaseData WHERE CODIGO = {0} END", nc.Codigo, num);
```

I hope that it may help somebody!